# Prove that F is surjective or f is homotopic at a constant

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let $F: D^2 \to  D^2$ be a continuous application such that $F (S^1) \subset S^1$. Define
$$
f: S^1 \to S^1: z \mapsto F(z).
$$

Prove that $F$ is surjective or
$f$ is homotopic at a constant.

Recall that $D^2 = \{x \in \Bbb R^{n + 1}: \| x \| \le 1\}$.

I can not express restriction of $F$ along with the continuous extension of $f$, I also have problem with contradomines because they are different.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'overjective'?

Comment: @CliveNewstead Maybe "surjective"??

Comment: Are you sure that the condition is $F(S^1)\subset S^1$ ?

Comment: yes, i'm sure, F(S^1)⊂S^1